# Convention for storing a number with a yes/no in DB

Tags: database, postgresql

This is a question about the best way to store information in a database.

I would like my database to know:
 1. If viewing is prohibited.
 2. If unlimited viewing is allowed.
 3. How many views are remaining (as an alternative to unlimited access).

#### Alternative #1:

Field #1 `views` (numeric).
- Unlimited views allowed = `nil`
- 30 views allowed/remaining = `30`
- No views allowed = `0`

#### Alternative #2:

Field #1 `views_allowed` (true/false), Field #2 `views_remaining` (numeric).
- No views allowed: `views_allowed = false`, `views_remaining = nil`
- 30 views remaining: `views_allowed = true`, `views_remaining = 30`
- Unlimited views allowed: `views_allowed = true`, `views_remaining = nil`

Which of the above would you pick, or would you use some other solution? I'd rather use one field than two if it works nicely, but version #1 seems a little unclear and may be harder to debug in future with the nil vs 0 convention.

Comment: I sure like alternate #1, but with 9999999 instead of nil for unlimited views allowed.  That way you could monitor the actual usage of your unlimited clients as well.  Plus the nil thing is not intuitive.

Comment: @zipzit I shied away from this approach because it seems like it is technically introducing a bug, albeit one that may be unlikely to occur. That said, I really like your point about monitoring actual usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for alternative 1 with a few tweaks:

1. Don't use `nil` for unlimited, as that could introduce unexpected behavior, since *SQL* has *three-valued logic*, and while you've defined `nil` to be "unlimited", using that value in aggregate functions and similar could have unexpected behavior. The one that immediately comes to mind is using [`count(expression)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), which will return the "number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null". This means that your unlimited-view items would not be counted in that case (implying that they have no views instead)
2. Use `-1` for unlimited. This will avoid the issue I mentioned above with `count` et al, not conflict with `0` and not require a large magic number which, in theory, could actually be hit, however unlikely. ('unlimited' views would subtract one from the count, but if that is a substantial issue in your case it can be handled via a `CASE` statement.)
3. Rename the column `views_remaining`. This makes it clearer in the future the behavior surrounding that column, bringing in some clarity from alternative 2 without the complexity of adding a second column that needs to remain in sync with the first.